# play video in background with responsive and HTML5

Tags: jquery, css, html

I would like to have CSS trick which can play video in background within full browser width and it should auto resize with browser size... Also it must play with Safari so please mention supported video file types.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/ and http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/knqyK

Comment: +1 for the html5rocks.com tutorial.  I used that tutorial to do exactly what you are describing, and it covers all of the the pitfalls amongst different browsers as well as mobile.

Comment: @jeff is there any online tool to convert video for different OS? You might have that idea too as you already done this before :)

Comment: @paras I had an agency prepare the videos for me, so sorry I don't know of one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be helpful to you

Set the height of the body to 100%***(no need to set width of body to 100%, but don't set the body width to less than 100%)*** and in the body add video element as direct child and set both height and width of the video to 100%.

```
--------HTML code-------

<body>
   <video>..</video>
</body>

--------CSS code--------

body{
  height: 100%;
}
video{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Could you please mention video type file too which I was requested?